# What is the difference between standard deviation and average of absolute difference of any two numbers?

Tags: standard-deviation

For a set of data $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ and its mean $x'$, the standard deviation is calculated by

$$
 \sqrt{\frac{\sum_i(x_i - x')^2}{n}}
$$
, while the absolute difference of any two numbers can be computed by

$$
\frac{\sum_i|x_i - x_{i+1}|}{n}.
$$

What  is the difference of those two values?

(Added Below:)
Both measure average distance among data points.
How do they differ and how are they used in practice?

Comment: How they're defined, I guess? I'm not sure what kind of an answer you're looking for. Do you mean their applications, use cases, motivation? If not, what?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. Both are measuring sort of average distance among data points. In this sense, I'm wondering how they differ and how they are used in applications.

Comment: Well, all I can say is that the first one is much more popular and used more often.